# Plotting a complex inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

So I am looking at the exercise:

"Plot $|z-3i| + |z-4| > 7 $ in the complex plane."

I have done similar exercises by using $z = x + iy $ and treating the problem as a real valued inequality, but in this case it yields a rather nasty result. I know that I can intuit $|z-c|$ as the geometric distance between z and c, and if I follow this line of thinking I can see some properties of the region but not its boundary.

I have the feeling there is an easy way to approach this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Fixed two points $A$ and $B$, an ellipse is the locus of points $P$ whose sum of the distances to $A$ and $B$ (i.e. $d(P,A)+d(P,B)$) is constant.

Comment: Awesome. Knew I was forgetting something. Now I can plot the graph by using linear equations for the major and minor axes and locating their endpoints using the stated restriction. How would I come up with the description of this set algebraically?

Comment: @Diophanties I'm not sure the problem is meant to be "solved" that way. You would have to make a change of coordinates to simplify the expression.